# Installing LILO on rEFI on Macbook which has 3 partitions: Mac OS X, Windows, Linux

Tags: linux, mac, osx-snow-leopard, bootloader, lilo

My Macbook has Windows and Mac OS X installed already.

I try to install Ubuntu on the unused partion and the installation is done. However, the Linux partition does not appear on the rEFI boot loader. My friend suggests me to install LILO or reinstall rEFI.

My hard disk has 4 partitions currently:

- rEFI partition
- Mac OS X partition
- Windows partition
- Linux partition.

I am seeking some advice on this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure of why, but I believe you need to do more than create a new partition to triple boot on a mac. There's a how-to here: http://wiki.onmac.net/index.php/Triple_Boot_via_BootCamp

Comment: Doesn't help answer the problem.